# Problems finding the cause of SIGSEGV while using a native fortran library using JNA

Tags: java, fortran, native, jna, coredump

I'm interfacing with a native Fortran library (physics) from Java/Scala using `JNA`, invoked using the Apache Spark distributed computing framework.

The following reports are produced using my library `/opt/MYORG/hdd/usr/local/lib/mylib.so` compiled with `ifort` and debug compiler options

```
-shared -fPIC -save -g -check all -fpe0 -traceback -static -static-intel -Bstatic
```

My executors crash from time to time because of a `SIGSEGV`, indicated by the JVM error-Report:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fea0f490700, pid=33080, tid=140647778658048
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007fea0f490700
```

The full report is uploaded here: [https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/GDqXyIRNVkY86XYCXkorjiuE4bZm4AmnNWllXBhMVmk?*encoding=UTF8&mgh=1&ref*=cd_ph_share_link_copy](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/GDqXyIRNVkY86XYCXkorjiuE4bZm4AmnNWllXBhMVmk?_encoding=UTF8&mgh=1&ref_=cd_ph_share_link_copy)

I managed to create a core-dump which I analyzed with

```
gdb /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java core.33080

(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fed0a04f1d7 in raise () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fed0a0508c8 in abort () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fed0995b6b5 in os::abort(bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fed09af9bf3 in VMError::report_and_die() () from /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fed09960edf in JVM_handle_linux_signal () from /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007fed09957673 in signalHandler(int, siginfo*, void*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  <signal handler called>
#7  0x00007fea0f490700 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007fed0a7fcbc2 in __nptl_deallocate_tsd () from /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
#9  0x00007fed0a7fcdd3 in start_thread () from /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x00007fed0a11173d in clone () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
```

I further analyzed the core with

```
thread apply all bt full
```

(The output can be found here: https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/ZUmv6GEM2oJ0MCCqfnNEs2OOateJVGnhnxoHsJnbvBV?ref_=cd_ph_share_link_copy)

But I don't see any thread currently being in my own (probably faulty) library `mylib.so`, all the threads seem to be waiting. Nothing so far points me to the fact that `mylib.so` is causing the `SIGSEGV`, but If I replace the call to `mylib.so` with a Mock in my code (i.e. no actual native call), no `SIGSEGV` appear, therefore I conclude that the problem must be in the JNA call to my native library.

So far I tried the following hints: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/determining-root-cause-of-sigsegv-or-sigbus-errors with no success

Can someone help my to find the cause of the above `SIGSEGV`?

Comment: You _probably_ don't want both `-dynamic` and `-static` (you should probably drop the latter, but this sometimes varies by platform).

Comment: @technomage Where did I use `-dynamic`?

Comment: I am worried there can be almost anything with your Fortran library. Are you sure there is no bug in it?

Comment: FWIW your error report indicates that the faulting thread tried to execute data - the instruction pointer (RIP) does not reference a code page.  This is plausibly due to stack corruption - the return instruction pointer on the stack, referenced when a procedure ends, has been trashed.  Stack corruption is also suggested by the inconsistency in stack and base pointer (RSP/RBP), and the lack of a coherent stack trace.  Things to look for in the Fortran include (as usual) array bounds violations or interface mismatches between procedure calls and definitions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `-shared`, not `-dynamic`.

Comment: @technomage Thanks, I will look into that and try different compiler options

Comment: @VladimirF Not I'm not sure there is no bug in it. Actually I'm suspecting a bug, but I'm unable to locate it.

Comment: @IanH thanks for your explanation. I thought I can rule out Array-Bounds because I've compile my library with `check all`, this should catch these problems.

Comment: The compiler's runtime checking cannot detect all cases where array bounds violations occur - for some varieties of array dummy arguments the runtime does not know what the extent of an array is, in other cases, the compiler's checking of array bounds relies on the programmer having specified/associated the array correctly in the first place.

Comment: You might try [`Native.setProtected(true)`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.3.0/javadoc/overview-summary.html#crash-protection), which should at least prevent the JVM from catching your SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of bugs are quite nasty ones. You can try to apply following pattern:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo015

In this approach you can "catch" SIGSEGV inside your code. Then, you can try to get backtrace using backtrace function:

```
void *array[100];
size_t size;
size = backtrace (array, 100);
backtrace_symbols_fd (array, size, STDOUT_FILENO);
```

Please note that you shouldn't do too much inside signal handler.

Then, if you have luck you will be able to spot what was the cause of the issue.

Another approach is to actually debug JVM using gdb and see what happens there.

You can find sample of JNI debugging here:

http://www.owsiak.org/?p=2095

or here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNoD001

or here:

https://youtu.be/8Cjeq4l5COU

As already advised, try enabling bounds checks inside Fortran code. Sometimes it helps.

I hope that it will help.

Have fun with JNI/JNA.

Comment: Your first link is dead. Please consider summarizing the solution in the answer next time instead of only providing an external link.